# How to pass header using wireTap?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Now I have following flow:

```
flow -> flow.channel(some_channel())
                .....
                .gateway(anotherFlow, idempotentByHeader(OBJECT_ID_HEADER));
```

---

```
Consumer<GatewayEndpointSpec> idempotentByHeader(String objectIdHeader) {
    return endpointSpec -> endpointSpec.advice(idempotentByHeaderInterceptor(objectIdHeader)).errorChannel(errorChannel());
}

default IdempotentReceiverInterceptor idempotentByHeaderInterceptor(String header) {
    MessageProcessor<String> headerSelector = message -> headerExpression(header).apply(message);
    var interceptor = new IdempotentReceiverInterceptor(new MetadataStoreSelector(headerSelector, idempotencyStore()));
    interceptor.setDiscardChannel(idempotentDiscardChannel());
    return interceptor;
}
```

The problem here that:

`anotherFlow`is finished with `MessageHandler` which is `void` so anotherFlow doesn't return anything.

I tried to use following approach:

```
 flow -> flow.channel(some_channel())
                    .....
                    .wireTap(anotherFlow, idempotentByHeader(OBJECT_ID_HEADER));
```

but compiler complains because of `idempotentByHeader` return type so I tried to do following:

```
default Consumer<WireTapSpec> idempotentByHeader(String objectIdHeader) {
    return endpointSpec -> endpointSpec.advice(idempotentByHeaderInterceptor(objectIdHeader)).errorChannel(errorChannel());
}
```

but WireTapSpec doesn't have advice method.

how to fix it ?

### P.S.

I was able to write with changing return type of idempotentByHeader

```
            .wireTap(anotherFlow)
            .enrich(idempotentByHeader(OBJECT_ID_HEADER));
```

But now app can't start because of:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: If the errorChannel is set, then the requestChannel must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.ContentEnricher.doInit(ContentEnricher.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.onInit(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:98)
    at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. You are missing the fact that `WireTap` is a *Channel Interceptor*. It is not an *endpoint* like gateway to be able to accept an idempotent receiver interceptor.

I'm not sure what is your goal with that `idempotentByHeaderInterceptor`, but headers are really passed in the message which is going to be sent to that WireTap. Therefore you get access to the headers in the sub-flow subscribed to this WireTap.

Also your latest sample with `enrich()` confuses me a little bit. Before with a gateway you tried to avoid sending the same message to that sub-flow via `idempotentByHeaderInterceptor`, but now you send to `wireTap` unconditionally and only after that your apply such that `idempotentByHeaderInterceptor`.

So, what is the goal of your `idempotentByHeaderInterceptor` and where you would like to apply it?

Comment: Looks like my question is weird a bit. Now I've added a bit more context. And I was wrong when I wrote about header adding. Looks like second argument(**idempotentByHeader(OBJECT_ID_HEADER)**) of gateway means adding interceptor which able to determine if message was already accepted. So my question about how to replace **gateway(anotherFlow, idempotentByHeader(OBJECT_ID_HEADER))** with wireTap and save behaviour of **idempotentByHeader(OBJECT_ID_HEADER))**. But only the difference should be that I don't want gateway client awaiting of result as we discussed in the previous topic.

Comment: Right, so you move that `idempotentByHeader` into the fist endpoint declared in that sub-flow your wire-tap is going to sent.

Comment: Artem my subFlow looks like this **flow -> flow.log(...)....**   so from you advice I understood that I should do following: **flow -> flow.someMethod(idempotentByHeader(OBJECT_ID_HEADER)).log(...)....** But I can't find appropriate method in the API. Please point me out

Comment: Take a look into `bridge(Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<BridgeHandler>> endpointConfigurer)`. So, your `idempotentByHeader` could be changed to `Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<BridgeHandler>>` return type. I mean you still have that `log()`, but before it you place this `bridge()`.

Comment: Well. When I use **GatewayEndpointSpec** I able to write: **return endpointSpec -> endpointSpec.advice(idempotentByHeaderInterceptor(objectIdHeader)).errorChannel(errorChannel());
    }** but in case of **GenericEndpointSpec<BridgeHandler>** I don't have **.errorChannel** method

Comment: That’s right: an errorChannel is not its responsibility. I wonder what kind of errors you are going to handle there... you may consider to come back to a gateway() and return something valuable instead of `void` in your handler. Then you come dump that gateway’s result into `nullChannel`

Comment: Actually I just want to stay the rest part of configuration untouched so I expect to achieve errorChannel filling with the same errors as in the initial configuration. Actually last statement in most of my flows which linked via **.gateway(subflow)**  is **.handle(messageHandler)** but MessageHandler#handle return void. I have no idea how to overcome it

Comment: You can do it with a `@MessagingGateway` interface, a `void` method in it and use that `gateway` service and its method name in the `handle(Object service, String methodName,
   Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<ServiceActivatingHandler>> endpointConfigurer)`. This way you still can use the mentioned `idempotentByHeaderInterceptor` for thst handler in its `GenericEndpointSpec` configurer. The `errorChannel` should be configured on the `@MessagingGateway`. The point is that `.gateway()` in the flow is definitely for intermediate request-reply scenarios. It can't be used for one-way fire-and-forget.

Comment: Artem, I am confused a bit. I see that @MessagingGateway is an annotation. What should I mark with this annotation ? I see that handle has method **handle(Object service, String methodName, Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<ServiceActivatingHandler>> endpointConfigurer)** which allows to use any method of the bean.

Comment: for now my flow looks like: **flow -> flow.handle("myPubSubAckHandler","handleWithResponse");**  and it works fine on a small example I mentioned in the previous topic but on my real project I experience error: **nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, failedMessage=GenericMessage [...]';**

Comment: I understand that my description looks unclear but I can't find significant difference in my playground project and in my real project. Hope you can suppose smth from your experience

Comment: The `@MesagingGateway` should be used on the standalone interface. See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#messaging-gateway-annotation. The bean created for that interface can be used in the mentioned `handle()` together with a method to invoke an appropriate gateway. I think you get a `DestinationResolutionException` because in your real project you indeed return something from your sub-flow. But in case of `void` gateway there is definitely no `replyChannel` header since no one is going to wait for reply.

Comment: I will try to localize problem at first and come back to you with concrete question if have it